# Как получить координаты элемента?

Tags: javascript

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
 var d = getBoundingClientRect('button');
 alert(d);
```

```html
<button>window.scrollTo(0,100)</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var d = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
alert(d.x + ' ' + d.y);
```

```html
<button>window.scrollTo(0,100)</button>
```

См. [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)